# Как получить значения в таблицы Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Есть таблица с пользователями ***User*** и есть таблица с друзьями.
К примеру, у пользователя Joni есть друг Kate и Alex, надо получить их данные.

**id** = 1, **name** = Joni

**id** = 2, **name** = Kate

**id** = 3, **name** = Alex

И таблица ***UserRole***

**role_id** = 1, **role_access** = 2

**role_id** = 1, **role_access** = 3

Сейчас я вывожу их по Id, то есть у Joni есть друг 2,3,а надо у Joni есть друг Kate, Alex.

В модели User

```
public function roleAccess()
{
    return $this->hasMany(RoleAccess::class);
}
```

Контроллер

```
public function index()
{
    $roleAccess = User::all();
    return view('admin.roleAccess.index', compact('roleAccess'));
}
```

Вывожу список

```
@foreach($roleAccess as $key => $role)
  ID - {{ $role->id }} = 
    @foreach($role->roleAccess as $key => $item)
       <span class="badge badge-info">{{ $item->id }},</span>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Получаю ID - 1 = 2,3

Вопрос как получить запись ID - 1 = Kate,Alex

Comment: Вам нужно исправить и уточнить ваш вопрос. Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Что за данные в таблице `UseRole`? Какие данные содержит переменная **$roleAccess** и почему на дочерних элементах вы повторно вызываете **roleAccess**? и тп.

Comment: Узнать какой пользователь имеет отношение к другому ,получить запись ID - 1 = Kate,Alex. Переменная $roleAccess получает записи из таблицы User, вызываю не повторно, так как hasmany получает записи из таблицы RoleAccess чтоб увидеть отошения

Comment: Никто не знает как ?

Comment: Я попытался помочь, но я не понимаю ваш код, что вы делаете и какой результат нужен (не просто получить имя). Пример в дубликате вопроса более жизнеспособен. Вам нужно переформулировать вопрос и желательно код.
Как пример, Есть таблица `User` нужно сделать возможность добавлять друзей пользователю, сделал то и, то ...
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь,Попытаюсь объяснить , есть таблица с пользователями, и есть таблица с друзьями. К примеру у пользователя Joni есть друг Kate,Alex вот надо их и вывести, сейчас я вывожу их по Id, то есть у Joni есть друг 2,3,а надо  у Joni есть друг Kate,Alex

Comment: Вот контроллер     public function index()
    {
        $roleAccess = User::all();
        return view('admin.roleAccess.index', compact('roleAccess'));
    }

Comment: Так в чем проблема? Вы получаете **id** потому что вызываете его через `{{ $item->id }}` замените `id` на `name`

Comment: Прошу прощения, ошибся с выводом, вот как сейчас у меня выводятся id foreach($roleAccess as $key => $role)
  ID - {{ $role->id }} = 
    foreach($role->roleAccess as $key => $item)
       <span class="badge badge-info">{{ $item->roleAccess }},</span>
    endforeach
endforeach

Answer (score 1):

Если брать за основу пример с друзьями, вам следует:

1. Добавить связь **Many To Many** в модель **User**.

   Так как пользователь может иметь несколько друзей и быть другом для многих.

```
public function friends()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
}
```

2. Добавить **pivot** таблицу, которая будет хранить связи **user_friends** с колонками 'user_id', 'friend_id'. Обе колонки указывают на `id` в таблице **User**.
3. Получаем данные в контроллере. Не забываем использовать метод `with`в контроллере, иначе в шаблоне будет "жадная загрузка" с кучей лишних запросов.

```
public function index()
{
    $user = User::with('friends')->find(24);
    return view('layouts.index', compact('user'));
}
```